# Sending Large Data to Android Through NFC using ACR122

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I'm developing a C# application to use an ACR122U/T NFC contactless smart card reader to send data to an android. I've been able to send small amounts of data that are less than 255 bytes but I cannot send anything larger than that due to lower layers allowing a maximum of 255 for the send buffer. I understand that the only way to do this is through SNEP or NDEF fragmentation or maybe both but I cannot figure out how exactly can I implement that.

Comment: Not exact, but similar discussion [here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444436/nfc-snep-push-fragmentation-acr122u-to-android-ics-p2p