# NFC SNEP Push Fragmentation - ACR122U to Android ICS P2P

Tags: nfc, nfc-p2p

How is it done? The documentation is unclear and there are no examples.

What I do is the following..

I chop off the data into small fragments and then I send the fragments sequentially. The SNEP header is only included once in the first fragment. Do I need to change something in my SNEP header or LLCP? I don't understand how LLCP should be changed to make android understand the sequence of the messages? After the whole message is sent, android does not acknowledge receiving the message.

Examples would be much appreciated.

C# Desktop application trying to send data through NFC Peer-to-Peer to an android ICS running on an SIII. The contact-less smart card reader is an ACS ACR-122U/T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNEP Fragmentation needs to be implemented. LLCP Sequences numbers need to be taken care of and finally, I think there should be some acknowledgement messages in between fragments which is where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I understand the concept, just now how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement SNEP fragmentation and encapsulate the fragments in LLCP frames. Read about the LLCP protocol in the NFC forum.

Comment: Yes, but how? I'd like to see examples.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, is exactly like you describe.

They change between them consecutive chunks like is specified in the SNEP protocol

Check this classes, i've tested them and works fine in 4.0.4 (not working on => 4.1)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ismb-snep-java/wiki/SNEP_From_ACR122_To_Phone

I've used those classes and worked fine for me

Comment: No, this only sends a maximum of one fragment, limited to the MIU size.